# How to know when an async-component finishes rendering

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an async component, registered as mentioned in the [Handling-Loading-State](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Handling-Loading-State) guidelines, and a data variable (`computed` or `watch` are possible too):

```js
// LoadingPageView.vue

const AsyncComponent = () => ({
  component: import ('./MyComponent.vue'),
  loading: LoadingComponent,
  error: ErrorComponent,
  delay: 200,
  timeout: 3000
})

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isComponentRendered: false,
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I want `isComponentRendered` to be true when `AsyncComponent` finishes rendering.

How can we watch or listen to `AsyncComponent` rendering state?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mounted`:

```
mounted: function () {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
        // Code that will run only after the entire view has been rendered.
        // i.e Set isComponentRendered = true here.
    })
}
```

See docs here for this exact example: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks

Comment: Seems indeed like a safe bet. But if there are other components that take longer to render (for instance, they get their data from http requests), I will be waiting for them to finish rendering even though the relevant `AsyncComponent` is ready